# Basic ruby class inquiry - do I need to add an empty array to initialize?

Tags: ruby

Given the test code below, we need to create a class and methods to make the test code work. So far, I have gotten the test code to work - up until the def kids and def family method. When I run the code in irb, I currently get the feedback for family method - Bobby has two children: Bobby, . That's obviously not what it's supposed to be, supposed to be Tim and Sam listed as Bobby's kids. Do I need to create an array and put it in the initialize method?

```
class Person

attr_accessor :age

  def initialize(name, age)
   @name = name
   @age = age
end

 def birthday
   @age += 1
end

 def kids
   kids = []
   kids << @name
end

 def family
  puts "Bobby has 2 children: #{kids[0]}, #{kids[1]}"
end

 end


bobby = Person.new("Bobby", 28)
bobby.age  #=> 28
bobby.birthday
bobby.birthday
bobby.age  #=> 30

tim = Person.new("Tim", 1)
sam = Person.new("Sam", 1)

bobby.kids << tim
bobby.kids << sam

bobby.family  
          #=> "Bobby has 2 children:
          # =>  Tim,
          # =>  Sam"
```

Comment: Thanks Bala - but that's not helping me solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you are calling kids you are overwritting the kids array and returning it with one element. So to fix add

> @kids = []

to the initialiser

and add an add_kid method

```
def add_kid kid
   kids << kid
end
```

and make the current kids just a getter

```
def kids
  kids
end
```

Finally change family to

```
def family
  puts "Bobby has 2 children: #{kids[0].name}, #{kids[1].name}"
end
```

This fixes it by adding a separate getter and a setter rather than trying to use to old kids method which tried to do both

Comment: Thank you ob264! This helped tremendously, and I now understand why I needed the array in the initialize method, and adding that other add_kid, and just making the current kids a getter. Awesome.